# change the settings icon in SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, 2016

I want to change the default SharePoint icons like site settings icon

Is it possible? Please help me with the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change Icon from Master Page. Please share the screenshot of your page, to explain which Icon you are referring, if I miss-understood the question..

```
<div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell">
                                    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSiteLogo" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
                                        <SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink CssClass="ms-siteicon-a" runat="server" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic" >
                                            <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=44" runat="server"/>
                                        </SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink>
                                    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
                                </div>
```